# Make sure all dicts in a list have the same keys

Tags: list, dictionary, set, python

I have a list with dictionaries like

```
[{'x': 42}, {'x': 23, 'y': 5}]
```

and want to make sure all dicts have the same keys, with values of `None` if the key was not present in the original dict. So the list above should become

```
[{'x': 42, 'y': None}, {'x': 23, 'y': 5}]
```

What's the most beautiful and pythonic way to do this? Current approach:

```
keys = reduce(lambda k, l: k.union(set(l)), [d.keys() for d in my_list], set())
new_list = [dict.fromkeys(keys, None) for i in xrange(len(my_list))]
for i, l in enumerate(my_list):
    new_list[i].update(l)
```

But especially the first two lines seem kind of clumsy. Ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you should use named tuples instead of dictionaries.

Comment: which dict is the "original one"?

Comment: There is no *'original'* i think

Comment: @Nkosinathi:  Using `defaultdict(lambda: None)` for your original dicts might solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import chain 
>>> l = [{'x': 42}, {'x': 23, 'y': 5}]
>>> all_keys = set(chain.from_iterable(l))   
>>> for d in l:
        d.update((k,None) for k in all_keys-d.viewkeys())


>>> l
[{'y': None, 'x': 42}, {'y': 5, 'x': 23}]
```

Comment: Interesting nesting of generators! I think I have never seen this construction before, and quite honestly, I'm not quite sure whether I understand why it works... care to elaborate?

Comment: It's just the same as nested for loops, read it from left to right like: `for d in l: for k in d: k`. But the k is on the left side since its a list comprehension. So it goes through every dictionary in l and then through every key in that dictionary.

Comment: +1.  Also, I'm too lazy to check, but I wonder if `d.update((k,None) for k in all_keys  if k not in d)` would perform better than `d.update((k,None) for k in all_keys-d.viewkeys())`.

Comment: Nice, although `chain` seems to be faster (list with ~3000 dicts of ~10 keys each):

`%timeit set(k for d in l for k in m)` : `1000 loops, best of 3: 4.86 ms per loop`
`%timeit set(chain.from_iterable(l))`: `1000 loops, best of 3: 2.61 ms per loop`

Comment: @Nkosinathi Changed to `chain.from_iterable`, you are correct it is a lot better.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this:

```
from itertools import chain

dicts = [{'x': 42}, {'x': 23, 'y': 5}]

keys = set(chain.from_iterable(dicts))
for item in dicts:
     item.update({key: None for key in keys if key not in item})
```

Giving us:

```
[{'y': None, 'x': 42}, {'y': 5, 'x': 23}]
```

We make a set from all the keys in all the dictionaries, then we loop through the `dict`s updating with any values they don't have.

An alternative to using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` would be be to do `reduce(or_, [dict.keys() for dict in dicts])`, using `functools.reduce()` (in 3.x, the `reduce()` builtin in 2.x) and `operator.or_`, although I feel this is less readable.

If you wanted to create a new list, rather than updating the old one, simply replace the for loop with:

```
newdicts = [{key: item.get(key, None) for key in keys} for item in dicts]
```

Comment: yup.  chain is "flatten".  but do you need to pull keys from the dict?  if you just iterated over the dict, you'd get the keys... ie `set(chain({1: 2},{3: 4}))` gives `set([1, 3])`

Comment: @andrewcooke This is true, changed.

Answer (score 2):

This creates a new list of dictionaries, all of them with complete keys:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> l = [{'x': 42}, {'x': 23, 'y': 5}]
>>> all_keys = set(it.chain.from_iterable(l))
>>> [dict((k, a.get(k, None)) for k in all_keys) for a in l]
[{'x': 42, 'y': None}, {'x': 23, 'y': 5}]
```